# Existence of solutions to quadratic vector equation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, quadratic-forms

Given
$$A_{i,j,k} X_j^* X_k + C_i = 0$$
where $_{i,j,k}$ and $_i$ are arbitrary complex numbers for all $, $ which are $$-dimensional indices and $i$ which is an $m$-dimensional index where $m<N$. Note $*$ is complex conjugation and there is a summation for repeated indices. Are there conditions on $A$ and $C$ to guarantee the existence of a solution to this set of equations?

Comment: One can formulate this in terns of Hermitian matrices $R_i$  and $S_i$ so that $A_i=R_i + \sqrt{-1} S_i$. The equations then become $X^t R_i X^* + D_i=0$ and $X^t S_i X^* + E_i=0$ where $C_i=D_i + \sqrt{-1} E_i$. Note that $D_i$ and $E_i$ are real numbers.